# React - How to import hook value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, react-hooks, return-value

I have a LessonThemes component, which allows you to switch between checkboxes and change the color of the block, the problem is that when importing a component inside the Test component, I do not quite understand how to get the `color` value to apply it inside the Test component

**LessonThemes.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function LessonThemes() {
    const [color, setColor] = useState(localStorage.getItem("color"));

    const [themes, setThemes] = useState([
        { name: "G", color: "green" },
        { name: "R", color: "red" },
        { name: "B", color: "blue" },
    ])

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("color", color);
    })

    const SideBarPageContent = (SideBarPageContentBackground) => {
        localStorage.setItem('color', SideBarPageContentBackground);
        setColor(SideBarPageContentBackground);
    }

    return (
        <>
            {
                themes.map((theme, index) => {
                    return (
                        <label key={index}>
                            <input
                                onChange={() => SideBarPageContent(theme.color)}
                                type="radio"
                                name="background"
                            />{theme.name}</label>
                    );
                })
            }
        </>
    );
}
```

Now when importing the LessonThemes component inside the Test component, I need to get the `color` value

**Lesson.jsx**

```
import React from "react";

export default function Test(props) {

    return (
       <div style={{background: color}}>
          <LessonThemes />
       </div>
    );
}
```

Please pay attention to the line of code `style={{background: color}}` this code does not work, I just want to show what result I want to achieve and how can I get the value of `color`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you solve the problem that you're having by doing either:

1. Set the parent and child relationships correctly. If you have the code going from:
   App > Lesson Themes > Lesson > Test
   then you can pass a prop from Lesson Themes down to Lesson and down to Test.
2. Use the [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to manage a global variable for color and set that in your Lesson Themes and then use it in the Test component

Comment: It's a pretty good idea just the LessonThemes component is only used inside the Test component. Do you think it is worth using React Context if this component is not used anywhere other than the Test component?

Comment: Then I wouldn't bother with setting up a React Context, simply make sure to have the correct Parent > Child  setup and pass the color down as a prop. All the best.